# Illustrator export gives a huge white border

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export

I am trying to export a business card size in Adobe Illustrator but each time I export, I get this annoyingly huge white borders that are unecessary, even if I save it as .png, any ideas? (click image to see the border because its white like the page)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you save using 'Save for Web', uncheck 'Clip to Artboard' before exporting.

If you save as PDF (which you actually should be doing for print), make sure your artboard size is the same as the card size.